# How can I simplify $ x^{a + ib} + y^{a+ib} = r^{a+ib} $ to not use complex numbers at all?

Tags: complex-numbers

If I have the equation:

$$ x^{a + ib} + y^{a+ib} = r^{a+ib} $$

It can be simplified to:

$$ x^a e^{i b \ln x} + x^a e^{i b \ln y} = r^a e^{i b \ln r} $$

and then to:

$$ \left(x^a\cos (b\ln x)+y^a\cos (b\ln y)-t^a\cos (b\ln r)\right)\left(x^a\sin (b\ln x)+y^a\sin (b\ln y)-t^a\sin (b\ln r)\right)=0 $$

However, the logarithm of a negative number is a complex number and I want to get away from that.

Comment: So.... you want to do the impossible???

Answer (score 0):

$b \ln x$ = $\ln x^b$ so if b is even there is no need for complex numbers.

I am unsure of how to solve the problem if $b$ is odd.

Comment: Do you really think this is an answer to **your** problem ?!? It answers nothing...

Comment: @JeanMarie b being even is a common case.

Comment: You have to add to your question that a,b are integers ($\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ ?) and $x,yr,z \in \mathbb{R}_+^*$: in fact $x^e$ is not defined unambiguously for $x<0$ (this answers your last question)... And the general solutions you are likely to obtain are the solutions to $x^2+y^2=r^2$ with $b=0 mod 2 \pi$